# Outlook for Mac: How do I configure a client side rule to match multiple keywords in the subject line?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, rules, email-filter

I use Outlook for Mac (version 16.16.8) and am trying to create a client-side rule to filter emails that have a list of keywords in their subject field.

I can easily set this up when it's a server-side rule but doing the same on the client-side seems impossible

Here's what my server-side rule looks like:
[image: server-side rule]

And this is what my client-side rule is like:
[image: client-side rule]

How do I have the rule match multiple keywords in the subject line the way the server-side rule does? I've already tried changing `bhk` to `"bhk" or "room" or "flatmate" or "roommate" or "flat"` but that has no effect.

Comment: I also test this issue on my side and got the same results with you. I’m afraid this is by design.
As a workaround , you can use the server rules.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you post a feedback in Outlook for Mac uservoice forum.https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac